# Globally setting the date and time within a php environment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with a codeigniter php script, which has a number of controllers which run daily, using cronjobs. Part of the input to some of these controllers is dependent on date. As part of my testing I need to evaluate the behavior of the script over a number of days.

Is there a way to set the date globally within my dev environment perhaps at the level of the php.ini file in order to test the activity over different dates?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can define in corre controller and extend all your controller from core controller.

In `application/core` create a file by name `MY_Controller.php`(be carefull about name)

Next in core controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // set your default time zone here

    }        
}
```

Next in all controllers where you want to set default timezone, just extend from core controller like this

```
class ClassName extends MY_Controller {
```

Comment: The question was how to change the **time**, not the time zone.

Comment: Or in pre_controller hook.